# Add Bootstrap template to MeteorJS

Tags: templates, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a Bootstrap theme from https://wrapbootstrap.com/ that I want to use in my MeteorJS application. The issue is it has script tags like:

```
<!--[if !lte IE 6]><!-->
    <!-- Link to Google CDN's jQuery + jQueryUI; fall back to local -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery.ui || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery.ui.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></scrip>
                                                                                    <!-- RECOMMENDED: For (IE6 - IE8) CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]> 
        <script src="js/include/selectivizr.min.js"></script>                   
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="js/libs/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>                <!-- REQUIRED:  A small hack that enables the use of touch events on mobile -->
```

which don't work when added to MeteorJS. I know  tags don't work, but how would you acoomodate this designed page to MeteorJS?

**Later edit:**

I added the `script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>` above. All the above scripts are added in the `<body>`. The `google.maps` library is used in `lib/main.js` and it doesn't work with MeteorJS because it raises `ReferenceError`. Outside of Meteor it works fine.

Any ideas on how to add that Google Maps script from the Bootstrap Template?

**Later edit:**

The Bootstrap template has a `lib/main.js` file which is the last javascript file imported. Nevertheless, when I add it to Meteor, it seems to be run, but its effects are not seen in UI. For example, it executes this line `$(".chzn-select").select2();` but only when I execute it from the Console I can see the UI changes. This file is loaded last by Meteor. I also tried with

```
function load_scripts() {
var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "lib/main.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

if (Meteor.is_client) {
    window.onload = load_scripts;
}
```

with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These external themes might not be compatible with the default bootstrap included with meteor, so you should remove meteor's bootstrap package:

**Remove default bootstrap**:

```
meteor remove bootstrap
```

**Add your theme:**

Place your css files in your project's css directory, say `/client/css`

Place the themes javascript files in `/client/lib`

Don't worry about the script tags, or linking any of them or anything, meteor should take care of all of that.

***Also***

Meteor includes JQuery by default so you don't have to worry about including it in your project. To add jquery if for some odd reason you're meteor project might not have it use:

```
meteor add jquery
```

**External Apis**

e.g FB/Google Mapis API/Tracking scripts. Add them in the `<head>` section of your html file as normal.

Hopefully you find all of this cool!!

Comment: I find it really cool :) Thank you for your answer, it partially helped me. Now, I'm stuck with a Google Maps script - you can take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Add the google maps api in the `<head></head>` section of your html file

Comment: It works, but I have updated the question. I will mark it even though now it's not the full response. Thanks!

Comment: Its probably about the order the files are added, meteor adds the files in the order of filenames from a-z. Adjust the filenames to match the order they need to be

Comment: So I think rename this `main.js` to `zmain.js`

Comment: The `main.js` had to be loaded after all JS files and after the HTML had been loaded on screen. So, the solution is to run `main.js` in `Meteor.startup` function. The hint had been the `$(".chzn-select").select2();` which worked when ran from the Console.

Comment: It should also work by renaming it to begin with 'z', so that its included last. I know the team is working on solving the order issue, its mentioned at https://trello.com/card/package-system-overhaul-officially-open-package-system-up-to-community/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/9 . At the moment the automatic inclusion method uses a sort of a-z order to include files. I reckon main.js was included too early

Comment: I tried renaming it to `z.js` and be the only JS file in `lib` directory (i.e. the rest were folders). But the HTML was loaded after the JS was ran. Thus, much of the initial config JS of the page didn't work.

Comment: Ah I see. Meteor draws the html after a short while, in which case you can use `Template.render`. Ill have a look at your other post shortly on how to overcome the many renders.