# bootstrap template with meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am trying to use this bootstrap template https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview with meteor. I have managed to move the CSS, JS etc files to the public folder and broken the page down into templates as such:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Thooslo Backend</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>

    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. We have chosen the skin-blue for this starter
          page. However, you can choose any other skin. Make sure you
          apply the skin class to the body tag so the changes take effect.
    -->
    <link href="/dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <!-- Main Header -->
     {{>header}}
     {{>sidebar}}
     {{>content}}
     {{>footer}}
     {{>rtSidebar}} <!-- this one is supposed to be animated -->


    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->
</body>
```

I dont know how to get the code from the app.js provided in the template (responsible for actually animating the layout).

I tried adding this to the end after the body tag and adding all the JS code, but it did not work:

```
Template.index.rendered = function(){
/* your custom js */
}
```

How do I go about adding the jquesy effects such as making the height of the divs same as page height.

I have found only one post describing this: [Add Bootstrap template to MeteorJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184504/add-bootstrap-template-to-meteorjs)

Comment: Why don't put all the js / css files inside a client/lib or client/compatibility folder?

Comment: @Ethaan I did that, most of the template is working, but just the slide animaitons isnt (jQuery)

Comment: @Ethaan have not tried the client/compatibility folder. Do you have some tips for that? I will try that and report that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put client based js-files to client/lib or client/js
2. Use correct template rendering

   ```
   if (Meteor.isClient) { 
      Template.body.rendered = function(){
         //jQuery
      };
   };
   ```