# Integrating bootstrap in meteorjs 1.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Good day everyone! New to meteorjs environment here. 
I would just like to ask if what could be the file structure in inserting css and js files from bootstrap templates especially, MeteorJS 1.4  has it's new file structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to care about file structure in other to use Bootstrap in Meteor. Simply install this package [twbs:bootstrap](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap) and you will be able to use Bootstrap in your project. Use this command to install it:

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

**Update**

In my experience, to include a Bootstrap template in Meteor project you need to copy files (js, css, font, icon images) of that template to `client` folder of the Meteor project. Also some js plugins will require to be placed under `client/compatibility` to work.

Comment: I mean, not the bootstrap package of meteor but, other templates i wanted to install in the project.

Comment: like in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184504/add-bootstrap-template-to-meteorjs